# Is there a function which is only analytic in the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a complex valued function of one variable $f$ that is analytic in the unit disk $\mathbb{D} = \{ z : |z| < 1\}$, but is not analytic in any region containing $\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb D$ is a region containing $\mathbb D.$

Comment: See: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10831/example-of-continuous-function-that-is-analytic-on-the-interior-but-cannot-be-an

Comment: Wolfram MathWorld has a nice example in their article titled [Natural Boundary](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalBoundary.html)

Comment: Classic example: $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {z^{n!}}.$